# Converting a List into a Tuple in Elm

Tags: tuples, elm, applicative

([Crossposted](https://www.reddit.com/r/elm/comments/7o2w6d/converting_a_list_into_a_tuple/) to Reddit)

How can I convert a list of know length into a tuple of the same length? Is there a way to do this using applicatives?

More specifically, I am using `Random.Pcg.independentSeed` to generate multiple seeds from a single seed. I then want to assign these to several variables:

```
import Random.Pcg as R

let
    (seed1, seed2, seed3) =
        R.step (R.list 3 R.independentSeed) seed
in
    ... use the 3 seeds
```

If I need a fourth seed, I can increase the "3" to a "4" and add another in the tuple.

This is the best that I have come up with:

```
let
    seeds =
        R.step (R.list 3 R.independentSeed) seed
        |> Tuple.first

    ( seed1, seed2, seed3 ) =
        case seeds of
            [ seed1, seed2, seed3 ] ->
                ( seed1, seed2, seed3 )

            _ ->
                ( R.initialSeed 0
                , R.initialSeed 0
                , R.initialSeed 0
                )
in
    ...use the 3 seeds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general purpose way to create a function which returns tuples of varying length. You could use applicatives to create some helper functions like this:

```elm
tuple2 : R.Generator a -> R.Generator (a, a)
tuple2 gen =
   R.map (,) gen
     |> R.andMap gen

tuple3 : R.Generator a -> R.Generator (a, a, a)
tuple3 gen =
   R.map (,,) gen
     |> R.andMap gen
     |> R.andMap gen

tuple4 : R.Generator a -> R.Generator (a, a, a, a)
tuple4 gen =
    R.map (,,,) gen
        |> R.andMap gen
        |> R.andMap gen
        |> R.andMap gen
```

Comment: That might actually work. I can always add another `,` if I need to grow my tuple. A comment on my Reddit post said that tuples with more than 3 elements are going away in Elm 0.19, so I may need another solution.

Comment: No more tuples? :( If they go away, you can always define your own tuple types, e.g. `type T2 a b = T2 a b`, `type T3 a b c = T3 a b c`, and so on

Comment: Based on your answer, this is what I came up with: `let
        ( seed1, seed2, seed3 ) =
            step
                (R.map (,,) independentSeed
                    |> R.andMap independentSeed
                    |> R.andMap independentSeed
                )
                seed
                |> Tuple.first
    in
        ...use the 3 seeds`